# driver.connect() vs DriverManager.getConnection()

Tags: java, jdbc

The `DriverManager.getConnection` makes call to `driver.connect()` internally to get database connection.
Are there any pitfalls of using `driver.connect()` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.sql.Driver` is an interface, you need an actual implementation (eg `org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver` for Firebird) to actually do anything with it. On the other hand, `DriverManager` is a concrete class that abstracts (hides) driver loading, selection and usage for you.

Normally you should not use a `Driver` implementation directly. Stick with either using `DriverManager`, or otherwise use a `DataSource` implementation (preferably through configuration).

Using `DriverManager` decouples your code from the actual driver used. That means you do not have a compile time dependency on a specific driver. Changing drivers or even database system (assuming the SQL is compatible or generated compatibly) is then just a manner of adding/replacing a driver jar on the class path and specifying the right JDBC url in the configuration. That is assuming JDBC 4 automatic driver loading, otherwise adding the specific driver name to the config and using `Class.forName(<value from config>)` is also necessary.

For example, for SQL Server you have the driver from Microsoft or the jTDS driver (+ other third party drivers). Switching between those is - basically - a matter of adding the right driver to the class path and changing the URL in the configuration.

In the past, Microsoft even had a breaking change in their JDBC driver, changing both the class name of the driver **and** the URL. If you had hard coded a dependency on the `Driver` implementation, your code would break if you tried to upgrade the driver. If you had just used `DriverManager` (and had a config option for the URL, and - this was before automatic driver loading - the driver class name for loading), things would just have continued to work after a configuration change.

There are exceptions where you would use a `Driver` implementation directly (usually through reflection and still not hard coded), but those situations are rare, and unless you have a very good reason (and know what you're doing) then just don't do that.

Comment: `Driver.connect()` is just as decoupled from the JDBC driver as `DriverManager.getConnection()`.

Comment: @user207421 Using `Driver` is more tightly coupled than using `DriverManager`. You will first need to identify and instantiate the right driver to create the connection, while `DriverManager` will try each available driver in turn until one successfully connects (or all return `null` or throw an exception). Especially with driver auto-loading that is simpler than directly accessing `Driver` instances (and making sure your JDBC URL and the driver instances are the correct combination).